# export data from Django database

Tags: django, loaddata, dumpdata

how to copy records from one database to another django ?

I tried for the first database

python manage.py dumpdata material - indent = 1

material is the directory database
after ?

> material.json ?

do I copy this file somewhere? in the second database ?

Answer (score 12):

You can use this command to dump the data to a json file:

```
python manage.py dumpdata material --indent=1 > my_dir/material.json
```

And then this command to load it into the database:

```
python manage.py loaddata my_dir/material.json
```

Comment: when I write

python manage.py dumpdata material - indent = 1

material.json I created the file?

if i go the second directory

(env) C: \ 01_07 \ myproject> python manage.py loaddata 03_07bis/monprojet/material.json

I get

Installed 0 object (s) from 0 fixture (s)

Comment: Are the database tables the same as the tables on the server you dumped from

Comment: yes all files are identical. It's two databases with two different names

only records are different

Comment: Have you checked that the file contains valid json entries.

Comment: which file ? material.json ?

Comment: which file ? material.json ?

Comment: Yes and check that the model points to the correct app and model.

Comment: I have seven materials in the first database

Comment: when i write python manage.py dumpdata material --indent=1 i point on the datas of  the first material normaly I would find in the file the names of the seven materials I get this when I execute python...http://pastebin.com/V9ajirHM

Comment: all other classes of my model are missing in the file !

Comment: I do not fully understand your second to last comment

Comment: I must be in the file material.json all fields defined in the model
I have fields related to a single class

here is an example of what I should have : http://pastebin.com/8EP11RsC

Comment: If you dump the data to file and then use the 'loaddata' command to load the json file, what error do you get? this should go smoothly id the databases and app structure is identical.

Comment: (env) C:\01_07\monprojet>python manage.py loaddata 03_07bis/monprojet/material.json I get Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s) because the file is like pastebin.com/V9ajirHM and not like pastebin.com/8EP11RsC

Comment: I tried this : (env) C:\03_07bis\monprojet>python manage.py dumpdata material.Category material
.Material material.Property material.Physic material.Physic2 material.Physic3 ma
terial.Physic4 material.Physic5 material.Physic6 material.UniteProperty2 materia
l.Essai_Temperature material.Media2 --indent=1 but I get the same

Comment: Yes and how are you attempting to load it back into the database

Comment: If the model path is correct and the data in the fixture is also correct I also can not see why this would not work.