# Django: Transfer group permissions from one database to another

Tags: django, authentication, permissions, migration, admin

I have customized groups with custom permissions on my development server via the Django admin. I would like to transfer/migrate these groups along with their permissions to a production server. How would you suggest completing this task?
[Example of a group I would like to transfer it to production with these specific permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbjIr.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [export data from Django database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865353/export-data-from-django-database). [See also here](https://coderwall.com/p/mvsoyg/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata).

Comment: @sytech Thanks a lot for the solution. I have used the "dumpdata" method to backup three tables (permission, group, and group_permissions). Then manually deleted all records of these tables from the Postgres database in production. Finally, I used loaddata in production to fill these tables with the backed up records.